# Android studio forcefully shutdown computer while file indexing

Tags: android, android-studio

So here's the problem android studio works perfect earlier for me
but now whenever i open project it android studio would start normally up to the point where background task tell its's indexing file then my computer would stop

my log file is here [github link](https://gist.github.com/parthnvs/ae3086afdaa53a0e5c44)

here's things i already did:

1. reinstall android studio with diffrent drive
2. reinstall windows 10
3. update sdk components

please help..

Comment: do you have any BSOD?

Comment: no its directly turn off computer

Comment: mate not sure its the solution but i had this twice with other applications and i had to replace PSU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the problem is in the configuration folder. There is a hiden folder with all the configuration options. I had the same problem in Ubuntu, and I just delete this folder, and start again to configurate the IDE, but it doesn't shutdown nothing anymore

Comment: Could you finally fix it?

Comment: @AyozePérez, hi I am also facing same problem in ubuntu 15.10. Can you tell me which folder you deleted? how you solve this?

Comment: where can I find configuration folder